# Обработка ошибки insert

Tags: sql-server

При ошибке вставки записи Primary key таблицы все равно увеличивается - выглядит как глупая растрата. Почему так происходит? Есть ли настройки для этого? Думаю, уменьшение ручками этого id не лучшее решение. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Если вам когда-нибудь попадётся СУБД, которая переиспользует айдишники, бегите от неё куда подальше! Проблем огребёте немеряно.

Comment: Если ответ был полезен, вы можете принять его, для этого нужно поставить зеленую галочку слева от ответа.

Answer (score 5):

То что Вы описываете является стандартным поведением всех SQL баз данных.
Перед выполнением вставки увеличивается значение авто инкремента и только затем выполняется вставка. Это нужно для того что бы зарезервированное значение не могло быть использовано другой транзакцией.
При ошибке значение авто инкремента не уменьшается.

В большинстве случаев это не критично и никакого ручного уменьшения делать нельзя.

В случае высоконагруженных таблиц имеет смысл проверять значение перед вставкой или истользовать другие виды первичного ключа (например UUID)